# how to convert complicated json to some object in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, serialization, nsjsonserialization

In my iphone app, I have to connect to my server script to get some data from database. I get some json in string format which looks like this:

```
[
    {   
        "id":4,
        "title":"Lokacija 03",
        "address":"Zagreba\u010dka 777",
        "place":"Rijeka","post":"51000",
        "pivot": {
                    "user_id":"7",
                    "location_id":"4"
                 }
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "title":"Lokacija 11",
        "address":"Adresica 111",
        "place":"Zagreb",
        "post":"10000",
        "pivot": {
                    "user_id":"7",
                    "location_id":"3"
                 }
    }
]
```

I have tried to convert it to dictionary with this function but it was unsuccessfully:

```
func convertStringToDictionary2(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]
        return json
    } catch {
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
}
return nil
```

}

I tried to convert it to dictionary. If you have better way to do it (some other object etc.) I will be gratefully.

Comment: Because your JSON is an array, not a dictionary. The array contains dictionaries, though.

Comment: Your JSON is an array, not a dictionary (notice the `[]` around it). Use `as? [AnyObject]` instead.

Comment: Take a look at the [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) framework. It can help you dramatically simplify JSON to object mapping